# Testing a call to a rest controller from controller in Spring

Tags: spring, rest, unit-testing, testing

I'm using RestTemplate to call a rest controller from a controller, e.g.:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String formForUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    final MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts=...;
    restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/rest/something",
                        parts, MultipartFile.class);
...
}
```

How can I unit test that the URL called by the controller is correct. Is there any way to get the path for the rest controller (e.g. using such reflection technique)?

I don't want to run an integration test!

Comment: In the method, you're putting an explicit string literal, so cannot you use the same string literal in the test?

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow you! If you think that you have a solution please post it. I want to test the call to this controller that receive a post from a form in the front end and be sure that I'm calling the correct rest controller using RestTemplate, that I would like to mock. Suppose that I change the api of the rest service, then the test must fail because the path is not the latest. Would be nice to check this in an assertion.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? How to test that the mock was called with three arguments (namely the URL string, the parts and the class)? Or that the first argument, the URL string was constructed correctly to match the URL that the REST controller is mapped to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is not the correct answer, but maybe it helps.

Assuming that the rest controller (let say `MyRestController`) has the class declaration annotated with `@RequestMapping`, then I assume that you can simply get the currently defined path as follows:

```
final String controllerPath = MyRestController.class
                    .getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class).value()[0];
```

---

**UPDATE**
Why don't you try the following changes to your code. They are based on Spring, JUnit and Mockito. Assuming your controller is class `MyController`.

```
@Test
    public void testUploadPostCallsToRestService() throws Exception {
        final MockMultipartFile file = //create a mock for a file to be uploaded;

        final MyController myController = new MyController();

        final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        final MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);

        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myController, "restTemplate", restTemplate); //I assume you use Spring MVC from your tagging, isn't it?

        final MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).build();
mockServer.expect(requestTo("http://localhost:8080/rest/something"))
                .andExpect(method(POST))
                .andRespond(withStatus(OK)); //Or whatever your rest returns

        mockMvc.perform(fileUpload("http://localhost:8080/path/to/my/controller")
                .file(file)
                .accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()); //I hope you return this :)

        mockServer.verify();
    }
```

This works very well for me. Essentially, I use the mock for the rest service server that has to serve the `RestTemplate`. So, the latter will call the mock that behaves as you specified. Then, it is injected in your controller using reflection. Finally, I use MockMvc to upload the file and get the answer from the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Is method argument value capturing what you're looking for?

You can use a mocking framework to mock the rest template and capture the method invocation arguments.

I suggest to use [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) and [JMockit](http://jmockit.org/).

Controller class (the example is working code, so I want to show the whole controller class):

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.util.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("MyRestTemplate")
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String formForUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/rest/something", parts, MultipartFile.class);
        return "[{\"good-data\"}]";
    }
}
```

The unit test:

```
import mockit.*;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void testFormForUpload(@Mocked final RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        MyController controller = new MyController();
        Deencapsulation.setField(controller, restTemplate);

        final ArrayList<String> urlValueHolder = new ArrayList<>();

        new Expectations() {{
            restTemplate.postForObject(withCapture(urlValueHolder), any, MultipartFile.class);
        }};

        controller.formForUpload(new MockMultipartFile("data-file.txt", "various data".getBytes()));

        Assert.assertEquals(urlValueHolder.size(), 1);
        Assert.assertEquals(urlValueHolder.get(0), "http://localhost:8080/rest/something");
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The `RestTemplate` mock is passed as an argument of the test method. That's all you need to do to create a working mock.
- See [`withCapture`](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Expectations.html#withCapture-java.util.List-) call that I use as the first argument of `RestTemplate#postForObject`. The url(s) used by the controller will be stored in the list `urlValueHolder`.
- There're two assertions for the url list - that it was called once and that it contains the required url.

I believe the test is easy enough, but still I would recommend to refactor the controller. Instead of using mocks and testing controllers to verify the urls, I would suggest to move the url creation to a separate factory class. A simple unit test of the factory would be all that's needed to test the urls.

Comment: I'll test this asap! Sorry for being late!

Comment: It does work, if you have the respective bean defined (a concrete RestTemplate defined either in XML or Java configuration). You can use the original controller snippet from the question. Anyway, it makes no difference for the unit test, as it instantiates the controller outside of the Spring context.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class for generating links to controllers and controller methods in the [Spring Hateoas](http://projects.spring.io/spring-hateoas/) project. Specifically have a look at `org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder`. It will be able to generate URL's for simple `@RequestMapping` annotations, but if you use multiple mappings on the same handler method it won't be able to figure out which one to generate.

Also, if your controller handler methods return `String`, the link builder will throw an error, so change the return type to `Object` and it'll work.